# Immnunity Debugger Python API Incorrect code execution order

Tags: python, immunity-debugger

**PyCommand**

```
   import immlib
    def main(args):
        imm = immlib.Debugger()
        imm.setBreakpoint(0x411077)
        imm.setReg("EAX",0x0)
        imm.log("EAX: {}".format(imm.getRegs()['EAX']))
        imm.run()

    return "OK"
```

**Log**

```
EAX: 0
Breakpoint at 0x411077
OK
```

The log write happens before `setBreakpoint()` according to the log.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like "Breakpoint at" means "the breakpoint was hit", not "breakpoint was set".

The breakpoint can be only triggered *once the program is running*. Since you call `log()` before `run()`, the log message is printed first. If you want to log *when the breakpoint is hit*, you need to use another approach (not familiar with ImmDbg API so can't recommend anything specific).

Comment: You need to use a BpHook, see the documentation for more information

Comment: @JeffreyZ: you probably should post that as an answer (with a small example)